# Which Laptop Should I Prefer: i9-8950HK with NVIDIA Quadro RTX 3000 or i9-9980HK with NVIDIA Quadro T2000

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor, intel, nvidia

I want to buy a new laptop and after some research, I have two candidates. The prices almost match, but I can't buy both best CPU and GPU in my region.

I found one laptop with CPU i9-8950HK (gen 8, 6 cores, clockspeed 2.9GHz) and with GPU NVIDIA Quadro RTX 3000, and one with CPU i9-9980HK (gen 9, 8 cores, clockspeed 2.4GHz) and with GPU NVIDIA Quadro T2000.

The problem is that I found that Quadro RTX is much more powerful.

I need the computer for (primarily):

- Game development.
- Software development.
- Machine learning.

Both GPUs are very OK for game development. But if I understand correctly the Quadro RTX is better for ML.

So I ask:

- How much is gen 9 better than gen 8, also consider 8-cores vs. 6-cores but higher clockspeed?
- Is the difference between the CPUs will affect more than the difference between the GPUs? Note that if I cannot do ML with Quadro T2000 there's no choice and I'll but the first laptop - ML is mandatory, but all three usages are equal in need.

If the computers are roughly equal I prefer the second because of the weight (1.78kg vs 2.6kg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's comparisons of the two CPUs which show the superiority of the i9-9880HK:

https://versus.com/en/intel-core-i9-8950hk-vs-intel-core-i9-9880h

https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-Core-i9-9980HK-vs-Intel-Core-i9-8950HK/3451vs3246

https://www.notebookcheck.net/8950HK-vs-9980HK-vs-9880H_9900_11341_11348.247596.0.html

And comparisons of the T2000 (Notebook) to the RTX 3000 (Notebook) show the advantage of the GDDR6 RAM in the latter:

https://www.notebookcheck.net/Quadro-T2000-Laptop-vs-Quadro-RTX-3000-Laptop_9858_9854.247598.0.html

https://technical.city/en/video/Quadro-RTX-3000-mobile-vs-Quadro-T2000-Max-Q

Comment: Thanks. I've seen T2000 has no Vulkan support so it's not an option. Just to satisfy my curiosity, can you provide a comparison of the GPUs for training neural networks?

Comment: No, I can't provide.